# Is it possible to search functions by parameter type or return type in visual studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, clr

For example, I want to find all functions in the .net class library requiring a Stream as a parameter, and all functions returning a Stream.
Is there any ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing and haven't found a search-by-return-type in Visual Studio.

My code is in a git repo, so I was able to find what I was looking for with a grep similar to:

`$ git grep "public IEnumerable<String> "` (or just `$ git grep " IEnumerable<String> "`).. the leading and trailing spaces can filter out many results.

Answer (score -1):

Look in to "Find All References": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4sadchd3(v=vs.90).aspx

You should be able to right click on any class and go to "Find All References" in the popup menu.  Note that this will also find any object references to this class (not just function return values or parameters).